# Pandas: Using df.eval with string variables as conditional filtering

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, eval

I have a simulated dataframe with one column created with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(1,201)})
```

which is just a dataframe with numbers 1 to 200 with one column, "A".
I would like to filter the dataframe based on a conditional statement like

```
df[df["A"] > 20]
```

but the column name, the boolean, >, and the value, 20, will have to be passed in as a string variable. So, I believe a dataframe.eval function in pandas should be used for this.
I created a function called select_twenty for doing this. Here is it:

```
def select_twenty(input_df, column_name, boolean_arg, value):
    evaluated = input_df.eval(input_df[input_df[column_name] + boolean_arg + value])
    return evaluated
```

In the function above, input_df is the simulated dataframe above, column_name is the name of the chosen column and boolean_arg is the boolean, >, while value is the value 20. The last three arguments are passed in as strings in the function call:

```
select_twenty(df, "A", ">", "20")
```

When I call the function, it keeps giving me a UFuncTypeError. I have searched all over Google and do not know how to resolve it. I have not seen an example too where an eval in pandas was done this way.
So, please, can someone help me with the filter? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is relative to the `+` inside of the eval argument, because you are trying to add the DataFrame column values with `boolean_arg`. What you are looking for is:

```
def select_twenty(input_df, column_name, boolean_arg, value):
    evaluated = input_df[input_df.eval(column_name + boolean_arg + value)]
    return evaluated
```

```
print(select_twenty(df, "A", ">", "20"))
```

```
       A
20    21
21    22
22    23
23    24
24    25
..   ...
195  196
196  197
197  198
198  199
199  200

[180 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now understand where the problem was.